# How to make the Broadcast plugin distribute images to several sites?

Tags: multisite, attachments

How to make the Broadcast plugin distribute images to several sites? 
I have the plugin from here:

https://broadcast.plainviewplugins.com/basic/

And the problem lies in that does not distribute the images to another site.

I have a attachment in the posted site in wp_blogs table but would like the plugin move both the file from original position and to the other direcotry structure for the other site(s) and then copy the attachment to the original and to the other distributable sites. Sure, some crappy hacking would not be too hard, but somewhere there would be a solution already.

Anybody, who knows anything about this?

Comment: Specific plugin mods are off-topic. Usually your best course of action is to either contact the plugin author and ask, or code it yourself and then send the author a pull request. Most plugin authors are open to suggestions but also busy and happier to accept ready-to-go code than suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to purchase and enable the All Images add-on to broadcast images:

https://broadcast.plainviewplugins.com/addon/all-images/

This is part of the Control Pack available from the plugin author for purchase.

Comment: We built a framework on top of it, and the issue did not solve by the plugin. The problem was that if you looked on another site than the uploaded picture was uploaded then you looked at the original MediaId, but in the broadcast table you have the bridge to the new site and can fetch the new MediaId from the other currently looking at.